# Display Picture by retrieving from nodejs api using angular4

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm having a backend nodejs server and a frontend angular web applicantion both are in different folders and running on different ports (Nodejs server: 8000 and angular client:4200). I'm storing images on nodejs server's directory in "uploads folder" using api and then storing the image path in the database. Then retrieving the image path using api to display it. I'm getting the image path like this (http://localhost:8000/uploads/030312-1618.jpg) but the image is not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using ExpressJS, have you set up the serving of static files as follows.

```
app.use(express.static('uploads'))
```

Source : http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

(Can help you further if you add more details such as any errors that you get, more information about the tech stack you use, etc.)